# optimize extracting text from large data set

Tags: linux, search, grep

I have a recurring problem where I need to search log files for all threads that match a pattern. e.g the following

```
 (thread a) blah blah
 (thread b) blha
 (thread a) match blah
 (thread c) blah blah
 (thread d) blah match
 (thread a) xxx
```

will produce all lines from threads a & d

There are multiple log files (compressed). Multiple are in the hundreds or thousands. Each file up to ~20MB uncompressed.

The way I do this now is first grep "match" in all the files, cut the (thread x) portion into a sort/uniq file, then use fgrep on the file with the matching threads on the original log set.

I'm already parallelizing the initial grep and the final grep. However this is still slow.

Is there a way to improve performance of this workload?
(I though hadoop, but it requires too many resources to setup/implement)

This is the script for the overall process.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    FILE=/tmp/thg.$$
    PAT=$1
    shift
    trap "rm -f $FILE" 3 13
    pargrep "$PAT" $@ | awk '{ print $6 }' | sed 's/(\(.*\)):/\1/' | sort | uniq >$FILE
    pargrep --fgrep $FILE $@
    rm -f $FILE
```

The parallel grep is a much longer script that manages a queue of up to N grep processes that work on M files. Each grep process produces an intermediate file (in /dev/shm or /tmp - some memory file system), that are then concatenated once the queue drains from tasks.

I had to reboot my workstation today after it ran on a set of ~3000 files for over 24 hours. I guess dual xeon with 8GB and 16GB of swap are not up to such a workload :-)

Comment: How are you parallelising the initial searches exactly? Maybe show us your code for the various phases...

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

In order to unzip and grep your files in parallel, try using `GNU Parallel` something like this:

```
parallel -j 8 -k --eta 'gzcat {} | grep something ' ::: *.gz
```

**Original Answer**

Mmmmmm... I see you are not getting any answers, so I'll stick my neck out and have a try. I have not tested this as I don't have many spare GB of your data lying around...

Firstly, I would benchmark the scripts and see what is eating the time. In concrete terms, is it the initial `grep` phase, or the `awk|sed|sort|uniq` phase?

I would remove the `sort|uniq` because I suspect that sorting multiple GB will eat your time up. If that is the case, maybe try replacing the `sort|uniq` with `awk` like this:

```
pargrep ... | ... | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

which will only print each line the first time it occurs without the need to sort the entire file.

Failing that, I think you need to benchmark the times for the various phases and report back. Also, you should consider posting your `pargrep` code as that may be the bottleneck. Also, have you considered using GNU Parallel for that part?

Comment: I like the awk replacement for sort|uniq, it makes sense. The log files a gzipped, so the uncompress eats a lot of CPU. However, I believe the biggest problem is that with such a huge dataset, creating so many intermediate files and processing them in parallel, generates a big pressure on the memory. The kernel started swapping, and when the swap space was fully consumed, my system stuck.

Comment: Can't you avoid the need to create temporary files now there is no `sort` - maybe by using GNU Parallel with `-k` option.